# Truncate a file on a certain pattern

Tags: awk

How would I go about truncating a binary file when a certain pattern is found?

For instance, I want to truncate the file at the first occurrence of the pattern `0xFFFFFFFF`.

I think something like `awk` could do the trick... but I'm not exactly sure how.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert to octal and assign to the record separator.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\377\377\377\377"} NR==1 {print;exit}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure, it's possible using Perl when you do the following

- use the command line option `-0777` to slurp all the input at once
- use Latin-1 coding
- use `s/\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF.*//s`

I did something like this a long time ago, but I don't recall the options anymore. For awk I have no idea.

Comment: Oh, `awk` is not a requirement, any solution will do. I'm not very good at Perl, could you provide a simple example?

Comment: Something like `perl -0777 -pe 's/\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF.*//s' < infile > outfile`, but I don't know how to set the encoding now.